# How to use googletest with premake5 and VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, googletest, premake

I have been trying to integrate googletest into my solution, but I get either nasty linker errors or can't add it at all.

googletest was added as a submodule: git submodule add 'https://github.com/google/googletest.git'

Have been trying configuring premake5 like so:

```lua
...
project "libtest"
    location "libtest"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp",
        "libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest/**.h",
        "libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest/**.hpp",
        "libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "mylib", // DLL
        "libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest/include/gtest",
        "libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest/include",
        "libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest"
    }
 ...
```

and I get `LNK2019  unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)    libtest C:\dev\mylib\libtest\LIBCMTD.lib(exe_main.obj)  1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to fix it :)

adding some extra file with:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

fixed linking problem, and cleaning up:

```lua
"libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest/include/gtest",
"libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest/include",
"libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest"
```

to this

```lua
"libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest/include",
"libtest/vendor/googletest/googletest/"
```

is enough.